# context menu in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, contextmenu

How can I create a contextmenu for an asp.net application. I want to display the contextmenu when I right click on a listbox. Please help me.

Comment: (the "flag for moderator attention" button is intended for flagging admin functions, site abuse, etc - we can't (necessarily) offer additional help with your question)

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery plugins to create context menus:
Here are a few:

http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/

http://wwwendt.de/tech/demo/jquery-contextmenu/demo/